# Как центрировать блок?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день изучаю верстку , и в примере в меню цена есть 3 блока с описанием цен и тд.Проблема в том что он разложил эти блоки по grid колонкам и получается у него одна колонка слева другая в середине 3 справа ,я же хочу написать эти колонки без `grid.css` даю колонкам `float:left` и и посленей колонке  `last-child:right` но вот средний элемент не могу центрировать в голове дать ему `margin-left` но думаю это косяк((( как правильно это сделать ?

Comment: вы хотите чтобы 3 колонки имели максимальный отступ от колонки слева?

Comment: Напишите по-русски, что вы хотите ил или приложите схему. На самом деле! Голову сломать можно.

Comment: Прочтите ваш вопрос еще раз и попытайтесь понять что вы написали. У меня не вышло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.wrapper>div {
  background: green;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.a {
  float: left;
}

.b {
  display: inline-block;
}

.c {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">1</div>
  <div class="b">2</div>
  <div class="c">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: смысл ? display-inline block просто отвечает за то чтоб они шли в одном ряду  как он может центрировать средник блок ?или я чтото не так понял

Comment: Вы получили ровно то что просили.

Comment: @Vasiliy Rusin  все норм не минусите я менял ответ